# redirect http tp https using mod_rewrite on apache 2.2

Tags: http, ssl, mod-rewrite, https, apache2.2

I have a working mywebsite.com hosting port at 8080. I was able to redirect the port from 8080 to open port 80 using mod_rewrite. Now i have a new requirement to redirect that particular http to https (ssl) port. I have tried so many possibilities in doing that and still failed throwing forbidden access error 403.

FYI I have not been using .htaccess for this access because mywebsite.com is owned by 3rd party and they refused to give me the path directory of the apps.

Apache: 2.2

OS : windows server 2016

`<VirtualHost *:80>`

`RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://mywebsite.com:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/%{SERVER_NAME}:80/mywebsitedoc/VirtualHostRoot/$1 [L,P]`

`</VirtualHost>`

`Listen 443`

`<VirtualHost *:443>`

`ServerName mywebsite.com`

`SSLEngine on`

`SSLCertificateFile "C:/Apache2.2/conf/mywebsite.com.crt"`

`SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/Apache2.2/conf/mywebsite.com.key"`

`SSLCertificateChainFile "C:/Apache2.2/conf/mywebsite.com.gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt"`

`</VirtualHost>`

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer as below. FYI it was zope web server running at port 8080 and i required to forward all 80 requests to port 8080

`<VirtualHost *:80>`

`ServerName mywebsite.com`

`Redirect permanent / https://mywebsite.com:443/`

`</VirtualHost>`

`Listen 443`

`<VirtualHost *:443>`

`ServerName mywebsite.com`

`SSLEngine on`

`SSLProxyEngine on`

`RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://mywebsite.com:8080/VirtualHostBase/https/%{SERVER_NAME}:443/staffportal/VirtualHostRoot/$1 [L,P]`

`SSLCertificateFile "..."`

`SSLCertificateKeyFile "....."`

`SSLCertificateChainFile "....."`

`</VirtualHost>`

Regards,
AA